# Running Ubuntu Server with GUI Desktop Environment | Dell PowerEdge R710 II

Tags: dell-poweredge, ubuntu-18.04, drivers, graphical-user-interface, graphics-processing-unit

Let me start off by saying I’m completely new to using / running servers and I’m currently 2nd year CS & Business student in DCU, Ireland.

I recently developed a program for automating sales invoicing at my work by using Python and AutoIT scripts, it works really well but I want to build on it and add more functionality to it over the next few months. I need my server to run SQL server, file server, continuous running of some python scripts and generally anything I need done to aid the development of this program. I picked up a Dell PowerEdge R710 with 2 Quad Core Xeon CPUs (2.9ghz) and 16gb of RAM. I’ve also got a PERC H700 Raid Controller in it running raid 1 on 2x600gb SAS HDD’s and a single 200gb SAS SSD in raid 0 (for installing the OS onto).

I would be confident-ish with the terminal but I don’t think I’m ready to completely give up a desktop GUI and use only a command line to setup the server and troubleshoot it when stuff inevitably goes wrong

I tried loading up Ubuntu 18.04LTS on it with a GUI but it was **unbearably** slow, I tried instead to install Debian10 to see would that make a difference, but no it was actually 10x worse

I’m not sure if I just can’t get the drivers to install correctly for the video card or if the video card just isn’t able to keep up with a GUI like GNOME

Does anyone have an R710 that has a GUI based OS (Linux) running into it that’s decently quick at responding? Or do I have to look in to upgrading my Video card (not going to be easy)

Again, I have to say that I really don’t feel comfortable using the command line based versions of these operating systems enough to run my entire server from it. That being said if that was clearly the only way forward I would just have to learn!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Drop the GUI install and use the command line. Install xauth and its dependencies. Install only those GUI programs that you absolutely need (and ween yourself off them) and then access them via a forwarded X session - is GUI runs on your desktop.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I’m going to have to look into xauth and what a forwarded X session is, as I said, I’m absolutely new to all this server stuff, sounds good though, thanks for your help!